# Why output is high even though trigger pin is high in Proteus simulation of IC555?

Tags: simulation, proteus, 555

In the below attached circuit of IC NE555 Proteus 8.0 simulation, TRIGGER pin (Pin 2)is set at Vcc. So why the output is high? It should be low since voltage at TRIGGER pin (Pin 2) is more than 1/3 of Vcc.

Please let me now if there is anything wrong in the circuit or is it a problem in the simulator?[image]

Comment: Probably not relevant, but you have no current limiting resistor on the LED.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger being low (less than 1/3 Vcc) forces the output high. But the trigger being high does not do anything to the output.

To force the output low, you must either drive the reset pin low or take the threshold pin (pin 6) above 2/3 Vcc.

Internally, the 555 is a set-reset flip-flop driven by a pair of voltage comparators.

Answer (score 0):

The trigger, TR, is active low. Try connecting it to GND.

Add a series resistor - 1k should do - between Q and D1.

Answer (score 0):

The highest priority input is RESET. But you have that tied high. The next highest priority input is TRIG. But only if it is low (below it's \$\frac13\$\$^\text{rd}\$ threshold.) You have that tied high, as well. So TRIG doesn't dominate, either. The next and last priority input is THRES. But only when it is high (above it's \$\frac23\$\$^\text{rd}\$ threshold.) Here, you have it tied low. So none of these inputs dominate -- the reset isn't actively resetting the FF state; the TRIG isn't actively setting the FF state; and the THRES isn't actively resetting the FF state.

This probably means (I don't know for sure) that the internal FF comes up in a default state that yields the result you see. I don't recall seeing specific documentation about the power-up state of the FF in the conditions you are using. But that's what you need to look for, I think. It will probably explain the results you observe, once found. (And which the simulator simulated.)

I know it is just a simulation and I'd guess that you are just exploring and that this isn't an actual circuit you intend building, but as Transistor mentioned you will need to use a current-limiting resistor in series with the 555 output and the LED (unless you buy an LED with a resistor or current limit built into it, I suppose.)